# how to display certain rows in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello I have a `JTable` and there a 3 radio buttons at the bottom when the user clicks the buttons I want the `JTable` to only show certain rows for that button. I've tried deleting the rows when the button is pressed but I get an error when i click the other button that re-adds them. Is there anyway I can just hide the rows when the button is pressed and show them when the other button is pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can just hide the rows when the button is pressed and show them when the other button is pushed?

Use a `RowFilter` for your table. So you need some data in the table that you will be able to specify a filter for. Every time you click the button you will need to change the filter for the new requirements.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thanks i think thats what i need to do ill have a read of that cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is implementing your own [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) (preferably by extending AbstractTableModel)